# How to calculate electric flux of special conditions?

Tags: electromagnetism

How to calculate the electric flux on something which has only one side like Klein bottle or a Möbius ring?

Comment: What is the source of the electric field?

Comment: Well...I am talking about static field...As we all know,electric flux is defined as E multiples dS,and both of them should be vectors.The question is how to calculate it when dS is not applicable.

Comment: @harshit54 Why make the question less general?

Comment: You can look at https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/electric-flux-on-non-orientable-surfaces.861862/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flux would always be zero because for every $d\mathbf{A}$ pointing in one direction there's a corresponding $d\mathbf{A}$ pointing in the opposite direction.

[image: From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusStrip.html]

This is a modified image from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusStrip.html.

Comment: you are assuming that one can define flux through a non-orientable surface, ok but how do you that?

Comment: @hyportnex Each surface element is orientable so orient one and the others follow. Then you end up with each surface element being doubly oriented. This is not a rigorous argument, but it seems to be correct.

Comment: My knowledge of diffgeo is almost nonexistent to comment intelligently but I am skeptical about that. Maybe some expert here can opine, @ACuriousMind, probably_someone, QMechanic ?